# I don't understand a line about HTML elements mentioned in MDN

Tags: html, web, attributes, element, mozilla

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/HTML_basics

> Note: Simple attribute values that don't contain ASCII whitespace (or
>   any of the characters  " ' ` = < > ) can remain unquoted, but it is
>   recommended that you quote all attribute values, as it makes the code
>   more consistent and understandable.

Above is the line stated about HTML elements and I don't understand it. Please explain with an example.

Comment: It says `<div foo=bar></div>` is technically OK, but don't do it anyway.

Comment: I searched ascii whitespace, but only found either ascii or white space, not ascii whitespace, please can  you clarify me,

Comment: ASCII whitespace is the set of whitespace characters within the set of ASCII characters, e.g. space and tab.

Comment: i can only deduct that attribute values which don't contain ascii code of space, <,> etc. can be used without these symbols(here  <,>,", ,',=,etc.).                                 am I correct to say this.

Comment: No, it's saying attribute values without ASCII white spaces or any of those symbols don't need to be quoted. I wonder if this might be better suited for [ell.se], it seems like it's the language more than the technology that's the problem.

Comment: sorry but I want to confirm, so when writing like such "attribute=attributevalue" , it's fine to not quote the attribute but if I use any symbol except = in between attribute and its value, code will not work, also it's recommended to quote attribute values.

Comment: No that's not correct.

Comment: what I meant was attribute=attribute-value(these 3 things ), is fine to use but not recommended, and if anything else then these 3 things Is used then attribute may not work.

Answer (score 0):

In basic terms, having this attribute value format in your HTML is valid:

```
<div class=class1 id=mydiv></div>
```

Note that we have attributes here are not sourunded in `"` quotes, and the documentation recommend to always include quotes for attributes values.

Having attributes in this format or style is **not valid** and will cause parsing issues in browsers:

```
<div class=cla ss1 id=myd=iv  ></div>
<div class=cla'ss1 id=myd<iv ></div>
<div class=cla`ss1 id=myd>iv ></div>
<div class=cla"ss1 id=myd>iv ></div>
```

Comment: so am I correct to say that attribute=attribute-value(these 3 things ), is fine to use but not recommended, and if anything else then these 3 things Is used then attribute may not work.

Comment: @Nikhil, not sure what you mean, I would suggest my friend is to never, ever write attribute without quotes, just to avoid any issues. In my answer I gave the samples where is it accepted and where is not, I hope I answered your question.